# Tools for creating app for Smart TV

Tags: java, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I should create app for Smart TV. I have googled, but I don't find something that can help me. And I want to know is it possible to create the app only on Java without JavaScript? What do I should use? Help me please :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

it totally depends on for which Smart TV platform you want to develop i.e Samsung, LG, Vizio, Sharp etc.
also there is other thing that some TV's have different OS for the same modal eg. LG have WebOS and Netcast series OS.

these have their own dedicated developer forums u can check that.

also u can develop using .net, HTML5, CSS, jQuery etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on the TV brand you want to deploy your app. If you want to develop in Java, you can make app for android TV: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/index.html

For Samsung, It's Tizen: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Features/Introduction but I believe it's HTML/JS development

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response guys! The app should be for Samasung Smart TV